# How to insert, prepend new elements to char array

Tags: arrays

I have problem with push to front new elements to char array. I have in my program a function which takes two arguments: a pointer to a char array, and a pointer to an int. This function fills an array with some data, and returns the count of elements in this array.

```
int function1( char* buffer , int* outSize);

buffer[1000]
int size;
result = function1(buffer , &size);

// after this a get some data in buffer and count how many data is in buffer. let's say 456 elements
// now a try push to front two new bytes as size this array

finallBuffer *char = new char[size+2];
memcpy(finallyBuffer, (char*)&size, 2); // here a get size in two bytes and put to finnalBuffer

// next I try just copy to finnalyBuffer received data from Buffer
strcat(finallyBuffer , buffer);
doSomething(finallyBuffer);
delete []finallyBuffer;
```

After this in *finnalyBuffer* I have only saved two bytes with size. Why don't I see data from *buffer*?

In finally I want to achieve new table with two new bytes in front. This two bytes is size old table. Let's say received data heve only 5 characters

`char table[5] = {'a','b','b','c','t'}`;

So size is 5. 5 in two bytes is `char size = {'5','0'};`

Result should be looks like.

`char table[5] = {'5','0','a','b','b','c','t'}`;

Comment: What do you mean with "push to front"?

Comment: And that is not C. Do not add unrelated tags.

Comment: Have you considered using a `struct`? It would have 2 members: `int numBytesRead; char buffer[1000]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure to understand exactly what you want to do but i have tried to figure it. See comments in code bellow i hope it will help you.

```
int function1( char* buffer , int* outSize);

buffer[1000]
int size;
result = function1(buffer , &size);

// after this a get some data in buffer and count how many data is in buffer. let's say 456 elements
// now a try push to front two new bytes as size this array

char *finallBuffer = new char[size*sizeof(char)+2];
short ssize = (short)size;
memcpy(finallyBuffer, &ssize, 2); // here a get size in two bytes and put to finnalBuffer

// next I try just copy to finnalyBuffer received data from Buffer

/* NOTE: strcat is for null terminated string. If i understand what you want
   to do you want store int in 4 bytes ?
   I assume size is the actual size of the buffer 
*/
//strcat(finallyBuffer , buffer);
memcpy(&finallyBuffer[2], buffer, sizeof(char)*size);
doSomething(finallyBuffer);
delete []finallyBuffer;
```

Comment: My purpose is very simply. Let's say I received  data which looks like `char table[5] = {'s','b','v','h','j'}` now I want to **push, insert to front** two some bytes so as now new table1 should be looks like `char table1[7] =  {'x', 'x', 's','b','v','h','j'}`. Thx for advance.

Comment: so you want to convert size to 16 bits (always < 65536) ?

Comment: Yes I want to convert size to 2 bytes, and after that insert, push these two bytes to front as [0],[1] elements to new table char.  For example in Qt library I can use to this in this way http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#prepend

Comment: YES !!! Exacly I want it. Than You very much. It's also funny that, because when You write answer to me I still working on code and went to this same solution, and ofcorse this works as well. Thank You again.

Answer (score 0):

Those lines are wrong:

```
finallBuffer *char = new char[size+2];
memcpy(finallyBuffer, (char*)&size, 2);
```

They should be:

```
char * finalBuffer = new char[size+2];
memcopy(finallyBuffer, buffer, size);
```

But I really understand few things of what You are trying to do.

**Edit:**

Now I see what you are doing and Olivier gave you the answer. If you don't want (or can't) use std::vector for your buffer you can save the cost of reallocating the array, anyway.

- Just start allocating for buffer 2 more bytes: `char buffer[1002];`.
- Then to store values you can pass the pointer to the third element: `char* ptr = buffer + 2;`.
- When you know the real size of the data, just put the bytes in `buffer[0]` and `buffer[1]`.

A struct should be advised.

Comment: I would like copy to [0] and [1] only 2 size as two byte.Thx for answer